# Issues in Force.com IDE after the latest V31 update

Tags: apex, force.com, ide

After the latest update to Eclipse after summer 14, I am having the following minor issues, please provide some tips to help me resolve them.

1. Whenever I create a project it defaults to offline. Never had this issue before.
2. No content assist - for example if I defined an object and no dropdown on available fields. I really do miss this.
3. There is 1 class for which I cannot see the outline, this is not the case with other classes. This is an apex class.

Answer (score 3):

At present, the only way to fix these is to move back to an earlier version. (The earlier ones appear to be still available based on the screen shot of step 4 of [Force.com IDE Installation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation).)

A (the?) bug list for the current version is [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues) and includes your item 2) and perhaps 3). I think 1) is a design decision. But AFAIK there is no published timeline for updates to the IDE.